# How To Solve Minus Value In Calculator Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to solve minus problem . `For example -8 -4 =-12` But I want to show the number of steps

```
for example -8 -9 -10 -11 -12
```

I want to solve problems like `-8 + 4 = - 4`and would like to display the number of steps between `-8 to +4 for example -8 -7 -6 -5 -4` through loop

through JavaScript loop

I have taken two textbox for value  one and two . now i am iterating through javascript loop but it is not working

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){

        var x;
        var minus;
        var textbox1=$("#value1").val();
        var textbox2=$("#value2").val();


    minus=textbox1-textbox2;

    for(x=textbox1;x>=minus;x--){
        alert(x);
    }

});
```

this is the html

```
<input type="textbox" id="value1"/>
<input type="textbox" id="value2"/>
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="submit" name="submit"/>
```

Comment: What wrong there? https://jsfiddle.net/kvLjfkrm/

Comment: no thats not a problem

Comment: Can you explain the question clearly.

Comment: Ok, could you clearly explain what is your problem then???

Comment: What's not working? Seems to be working just fine. Also, use console.log(x) instead of alert(x); a little friendlier..

Comment: You are using `.val()` which returns string. See my answer for correct implementation

Comment: The problem is that if textbox2 contains a negative number, the loop will never execute.

Comment: I think you are typing two negatives int to your input fields ..

Comment: yes i am trying to do that

Comment: @modgeek But you know that (--) gives +, right?...

Comment: this is wrong cause the submitt button will act like a minus ..you have `var minus=textbox1-textbox2`  if you give -8 and -4 minus variable will be `-8- -4=-4` and your loop will not start

Comment: lets say you are passing input -4 -8 what will happen next ?

Comment: in your calculator is the above submitt button a minus or a plus?

Comment: @modgeek please take a look to my updated answer.

Comment: @modgeek So what you want is somekind of loop: https://jsfiddle.net/7bdmhchw/ `Math.abs(textbox2)`  would return the number of needed iterations

Comment: @A.Wolff that is not what OP is looking for , your loop is starting from fisrt input and ending with the last one, he is asking to start from the first input till the result of the operation .

Comment: @Amani no it isnt. My jsfiddle just works as the accepted answer, just a little more compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){

    var x;
    var minus;
    var textbox1=$("#value1").val();
    var textbox2=$("#value2").val();
    minus=textbox1-textbox2;
    if(textbox1 >= minus){
      for(x=textbox1;x>=minus;x--){
        alert(x);
      }
    }else{
      for(x=textbox1;x<=minus;x++){
      alert(x);
      }
   }
```

});

> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvLjfkrm/3/)

Answer (score 1):

sorry for directly answer here.. but i am new to stackoverflow and it does't allow to comment if user has reputation < 50 :(

*use `parseInt(number)` or `parseFloat(number)` to parse the value into their correct type..

your code is runing like this. i think you're entering `-8` and `-4` as inputs..

`-8-(-4) = -8 + 4 = -4`
and `-8 >=-4` returns `false` so it fails and loop won't run..

please enter `-8` in first textbox and `4` in the second textbox the alert will appear (it's what your code is running).

#### UPDATE

I just saw you updated the description of your problem..

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
var num1 = parseInt($("#value1").val());
var num2 = parseInt($("#value2").val());   
var diff = num1-num2;

if(num1 < minus){
  for(var x=num1;x<=diff;x++){
      alert(x);
      console.log('x:', x);
  }
} else{
  for(var x=num1;x>=diff;x--){
     alert(x);
     console.log('x:', x);
  }
```

}
});

Also I have updated your jsfiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/kvLjfkrm/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is because `.val()` returns string.

Correct Implementation will be

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){

    var x;
    var minus;
    var textbox1= new Number($("#value1").val());
    var textbox2= new Number($("#value2").val());


minus=textbox1-textbox2;

for(x=textbox1;x>=minus;x--){
    alert(x);
}

});
```

Comment: Type coercion takes care of this however.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){

        var x;
        var result;
        var textbox1=$("#value1").val();
        var textbox2=$("#value2").val();


    result=parseInt(textbox1)+parseInt(textbox2);
    
    for(x=textbox1;x>=result;x--){
        alert(x);
    }

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" id="value1"/>
<input type="textbox" id="value2"/>
<input type="submit"  id="submitBtn" value="submit" name="submit"/>
```